# Bootstrap navbar fill active item with solid color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm building a page using Bootstrap 5 with a fixed top navbar and I would like the "active" item to have a solid background color similar to [here](https://www.wrc.com/en/video/).

When I open the developer tools I see that the items do not fill the entire height of the navbar, and I'm new to Bootstrap and quite rusty at HTML/CSS so I couldn't figure out what elements are relevant to style to get what I want.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img class src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Foobar" height="32">
  </a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item A #1</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item B #2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
            Active
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row ml-md-auto d-none d-md-flex">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link p-2 bi bi-github" href="#" target="_blank" rel="noopener" aria-label="GitHub" style="font-size: 1.2em"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. What have you tried? Add some CSS to the demo above as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A few things get you started in this direction:

1. Use the standard [navbar layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/#supported-content) so you have list items at the top level and not just raw buttons.
2. Remove the [padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) on the outer element with `p-0` so the list items are full height. Those could be made taller again with other methods if you prefer, as I've done here via vertical padding.
3. Add hover styling with some custom CSS. Here I've used a media query to only apply the effect where the navbar is in desktop mode (992px and above).

View this demo in fullscreen mode to see the result.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .hover-bg > .nav-item {
    padding: .5rem;
  }
  .hover-bg > .nav-item:hover {
    background: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light p-0">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 hover-bg">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex" role="search">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```